# "Bounded" meaning in programming

Tags: go

I am trying to follow below presentation

http://www.slideshare.net/borderj/concurrency-in-go-10662038

And I found this statement ,

> "typed BOUNDED blocking"

in here what exactly mean by BOUNDED ?

I tried gooling and found that BOUNDED BUFFER explanations but I am looking for more general understanding

Comment: Bounded means channels have a maximum size. Pushing when they're full causes them to block rather than grow.

Comment: Interesting use of the word "bounded" as I'm pretty sure that even the Go tour calls them "buffered"... or is that different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a loose way to say that channels have an explicit size, and sends block if they're full. By itself "bounded" is not a well-defined term in software development, though.